# Replace certain rows of data frame with values, on specific column, in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Make data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 'B': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 'C': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']})
```

Looks like:

```
    A   B   C
0   0   5   a
1   1   6   b
2   2   7   c
3   3   8   d
4   4   9   e
```

Make new column:

```
df["coolness"] = "no"
```

Looks like:

```
    A   B   C   coolness
0   0   5   a   no
1   1   6   b   no
2   2   7   c   no
3   3   8   d   no
4   4   9   e   no
```

Need to replace certain rows with "yes" in the "coolness" column.

Tried:

```
 df["coolness"].replace([0, 1, 3], "yes")
```

But doesn't work. Gives:

```
0    no
1    no
2    no
3    no
4    no
```

While this:

```
df.replace([0, 1, 3], "yes")
```

does it only on first column:

```
    A   B   C   coolness
0   yes 5   a   no
1   yes 6   b   no
2   2   7   c   no
3   yes 8   d   no
4   4   9   e   no
```

Comment: And what is the expected result ? You just tell about the wrong ones, not the good on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
df.loc[[0,1,3], 'coolness'] = 'yes'
```

Answer (score 0):

if 0,1,3 are index then

```
    df.loc[[0,1,3], 'coolness'] = 'yes'
```

if 0 1 3 are values of a column A

```
    def app(x):
      if x["A"]==0 or x["A"]==1 or x["A"]==3:
        x['coolness']="yes"
      return x
    f=f.apply(app,axis=1)
    f
```

result in both the cases

```
    A   B   C   coolness
0   0   5   a   yes
1   1   6   b   yes
2   2   7   c   no
3   3   8   d   yes
4   4   9   e   no
```